# Resume in Debug Mode

Tags: vba

The VBA programs I work with have error handling.  It is common for when the error is mentioned to me by the end user, the focus of the program will be in the error handler in debug mode.  In these situations, I want to investigate why the error occurred so I type "resume" and run the "resume" line of code.  Is there a shortcut key, button or menu option that would allow me to resume the program?  If I try to use "resume" in the Immediate pane, I get an error message.

Comment: F5 usually continues to run. Or F8 to step thru

Comment: I'm familiar with those functions.  Neither key will resume the code to the point of where it was prior to the exception occurring.  A simple divide by zero error and an error handler will show this.  I can type "resume" and run that line.  In addition, I can use line numbers in my code and some code in the error handler to show on which line the error occurred.  However, I want to be able to click on a button or use a similar method and run "resume."

Comment: Change your options to only break on unhandled errors and change your error handling to logging with debug.print

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want something like this.

```
Private Sub ErrorHandlerDeveloper_Test()

Dim uErrorMsg As String
Dim devStatus As Boolean

devStatus = True    ' Change to false when shared
'devStatus = False

Dim procName As String
procName = "ErrorHandlerDeveloper_Test"

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

' *********************************
' code that triggers an error here
err.Raise 11
' *********************************

ExitRoutine:

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    If devStatus = True Then
        err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
        ' Return to the error line and highlight
        Resume

    Else
        uErrorMsg = "Take note of this information and advise the developer." & vbCr & vbCr
        'uErrorMsg = uErrorMsg & "Error Source...: " & Err.Source & vbCr  & vbCr
        uErrorMsg = uErrorMsg & "Procedure......: " & procName & vbCr & vbCr
        uErrorMsg = uErrorMsg & "Error Number..: " & err.Number & vbCr & vbCr
        uErrorMsg = uErrorMsg & "Description.....: " & err.Description

        Debug.Print uErrorMsg
        MsgBox uErrorMsg, , "Generated in " & procName

        Resume ExitRoutine

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: No.  That bit of code has some good stuff in it but I am looking for a solution independent of current code.  I want a button or a shortcut key to "resume."  I don't think that what I am looking for exists.  An alternative would be to use the Windows API to run on the open event of where the VBA program resides that effectively creates the "resume" button in the VBA IDE.  If somebody wants to use the above code and they have numbered lines, they can use Erl to get the line number.